# How to use strtok in luajit?

Tags: lua, strtok, luajit

My code are as follow:

```
local ffi = require "ffi"
local ffi_C = ffi.C
local ffi_typeof = ffi.typeof
local ffi_new = ffi.new
local ffi_string = ffi.string
local NULL = ngx.null
local tostring = tostring

ffi.cdef[[
    char * strtok(char * str, const char * delimiters);
]]

local p_char_type = ffi_typeof("char[?]")

function split(src, c)
    local result = {}

    local pch = ffi_new(p_char_type, 1)
    local psrc = ffi_new(p_char_type, #src)
    local pc = ffi_new(p_char_type, #c)

    ffi.copy(psrc, src)
    ffi.copy(pc, c)
    pch = ffi_C.strtok(psrc, pc)

    while pch do
        table.insert(result, ffi_string(pch))
        pch = ffi_C.strtok(NULL, pc)
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "pch ok")
    end

    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "split ok")

    return result
end
```

When I run my nginx, there are something wrong happened!
After return by the while loop, the nginx worker process crashed with signal 11.
The last ngx.log can not run.
How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

```
local psrc = ffi_new(p_char_type, #src)
ffi.copy(psrc, src)
```

`ffi.copy` when given a string source also copies a null terminator, but your array is too small to hold it, resulting an overflow.

Also, instead of using `strtok`, consider using Lua patterns. They are safer, easier to use, and don't depend on the FFI.